# Not Able To Run Consolecommand From Cron Tab

Tags: php, yii, cron

I have written a `ConsoleCommand` which runs awesome from Windows Command prompt and also linux terminal. My problem is that , when I add this command in the cron tab I get the following error when it is been executed.

This script must be run from the command line.

What could be the problem ?

Here you go:

```
class ReportGeneratorCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    public function getHelp(){
        echo 'This command genearates Periodic reports'."\n\n";
        return;
    }
    public function run($args){
        echo "\n Hello world! \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: We need the code to start guessing : )

Comment: Please take a reading of [this blog-post](http://tariffstreet.com/yii/2012/04/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii-and-cconsolecommand/).

Comment: @fedorqui I am damn sure you wont figure out anything by seeing my code :)

Comment: @DreamEater Thanks so much for sharing the link. In fact I have also asked the author of same blog about this and still waiting for the reply. you could have seen my comment over there, but it says my comment is still awaiting moderation ! Forget it, My problem is not about how to create the ConsoleCommand, but how to run by cron job ?

Comment: Then please paste what you have added to your crontab. I mean: how to you call your command from there?

Comment: @Michael Härtl Thanks for replying. I actually have solved it by modifying the command ! I have answered my question myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I used to run the command from cron as

```
php /home/pathtomyapp/console.php myCommand
```

Now I modified it to

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/pathtomyapp/console.php myCommand
```

and that did it !

Comment: You don't need any `console.php`. You could just run `yiic` from your crontab. `/home/pathtomyapp/protected/yiic myCommand`.